# Data store appropriate for sensor data

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, sensors

What do you think is a data store appropriate for sensor data, such as temperature, humidity, velocity, etc. Users will have different sets of fields and they need to be able to run basic queries against data.

Relational databases like MySQL is not flexible in terms of schema, so I was looking into NoSql approaches, but not sure if there's any particular project that's more suitable for sensor data. Most of NoSql seem to be geared toward log output as such.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think I would use an RDBMS simply because of the flexibility you have to query the data. I am currently developing applications that log approximately one thousand remote sensors to SQL Server, and though I've had some growing pains due to the "inflexible" schema, I've been able to expand it in ways that provides for multiple customers. I'm providing enough columns of data that, collectively, can handle a vast assortment of sensor values, and each user just queries against the fields that interest them (or that their sensor has features for).

That said, I originally began this project by writing to a comma separated values (CSV) file, and writing an app that would parse it for graphing, etc. Each sensor stored its data in a separate CSV, but by opening multiple files I was able to perform comparisons between two or more sets of sensor data. Also CSV is highly compressible, opens in major office applications, and is fairly user-editable (such as trimming sections that you don't need).

Comment: Thanks for the input @JYelton. I've been using relational databases all along and was curious about alternatives. After looking into the problem more closely, I'm going with a combination of MySQL and MongoDB.

Comment: @Grnbeagle I know it has been a while ago since you posted the question, but if you still come here I would be very interested to hear about your experiences. Did you go with MySQL and MongoDB? What role did MySQL play? Any pointers for someone who is looking at the same problem a year later?

Comment: @kloffy if I remember correctly, we had feeds and each feed could contain any sensor data. I stored feeds in MySQL and sensor data in MongoDB with a reference to feeds table. Feeds had some permission rules tied with users and some other additional requirements I don't quite recall that made it appropriate to put in relational db. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Grnbeagle thank you for taking the time to comment! I suppose the benefit of having the feeds in MongoDB rather than storing JSON in MySQL is being able to perform queries on them? It's an interesting approach and I haven't found any real alternatives with that kind of flexibility.